# LiquiBase diff & diffChangeLog doesn't detect changes

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm trying to generate a changeset with the changes I made in my `@Entity`s

I have the following gradle setup. I'm using these plugins 
[liquibase-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin)
[liquibase-hibernate](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate)

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('com.github.waffle:waffle-spring-boot-starter:1.9.0')
    compile('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    apt('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.2')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.0.1')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.6')
    liquibaseRuntime('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}

diff.dependsOn compileJava
diffChangeLog.dependsOn compileJava
generateChangelog.dependsOn compileJava

liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      changeLogFile 'main.groovy'
      referenceUrl 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE'
      referenceUsername 'user'
      referencePassword 'pass'
      url 'hibernate:spring:com.example' +
                   '?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect' +
                   '&hibernate.enhanced_id=true'
    }
  }
  runList = 'main'
}
```

## Steps

1. .\gradlew diffChangeLog
2. .\gradlew update
3. Observe the initial database have been correctly created
4. Observe the DATABASECHANGELOG table have been correctly populated
5. Add a property to an `@Entity`
6. .\gradlew diffChangeLog
7. Note that no new changeset have been added to the `main.groovy` file. Instead the existing changeset for the entity have been altered. Rendering everything completely useless!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase does not generate schema from `@entity` but from changeset files.

You have to let hibernate/jpa/else generate the schema and then use `diffChangeLog` command. This allows you to generate a changeset file.

It could be easier to add your modifications in the changeset file, in parallel of annotation in your code.

Comment: I thought the liquibase-hibernate plugin enabled me to generate changesets based on model changes

Comment: liquibase-hibernate plugin does just that "generate schema from `@entity`"

Comment: @ahmedjaad just don't forget to compile so you can get the actual entity changes

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [wiki](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki) you should use `gradle diff` to generate a changeset file. Use `gradle diffChangeLog` only for the first master xml.

Comment: I can't recall what command I ended up using, but I concluded that the https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate plugin is utterly broken and abandoned

Comment: did you find an alternative?

Comment: Nope, I just wrote the migrations by hand while eating sadpie